# Regex slash Unnecessary escape character

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

When I execute `vue-cli-service` on my project I get the following eslint error: **Unnecessary escape character** on the following line

```
v => (v && /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-|\/]+\/?$/.test(v)) || `Stream format don't match`
```

the escaped character pointed by the warning is my second `/` (36 character). But if I remove it I get a syntax error. I can simply do an `// eslint-disable-next-line` but before that I would like to understand what is happening.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's point to the *first* forward slash - the one inside the square brackets. It's not necessary to escape it because it's part of a character class.

Comment: @vlaz thanks you are right eslint points me the wrong one the follwoing works:
`v => (v && /^[a-zA-Z0-9-|/]+\/?$/.test(v)) || "Stream format don't match"`

Comment: I've seen some linter implementations just being off by a few characters sometimes. At least one time it was because the linter was assuming that either tabs or spaces were used for indentation and counting the characters without noticing the other was actually present. Other times I've just seen it count incorrectly with a constant offset. It seems were unlucky and the error coincided with the second spot which misled you.